# No Software Updates since Upgrade to 18.10?

Tags: 18.04, updates, 18.10

It's been nearly a week and I haven't received a single update to install when compared to how often I used to get ones on 18.04. I'm new to Linux and therefore don't know if this is normal behavior or whether something is possibly wrong?

Comment: Post release, once any glaring [significant] problems are fixed, it's common for the developers who've been working hard to get the release out, get a chance to take a break, reduce their 'time-owed' and updates reduce.   The only updates I'd expect at this time for 18.10 are bug-fixes for reported bugs (that can't wait)..  We'll soon hear the name for the next release, and you may find the pace picks up again as their 'time-off' ends   *opinion only!*

Comment: That explains it then! I most certainly think they've deserved their break and I'm glad nothing is wrong with my OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post release, once any glaring [significant] problems are fixed, it's common for the developers who've been working hard to get the release out, get a chance to take a break, reduce their 'time-owed' (*banked or overtime held*) and thus updates reduce.

The only updates I'd expect at this time for 18.10 are bug-fixes for reported bugs (that can't wait).

We'll soon hear the name for the next release (often ~three weeks after release), and you may find the pace picks up again as devs return to normal work weeks.

Note: *the aforementioned is my opinion only!*

---

To check up on their work (ie. facts), you can see the desktop team's brief reports via

https://community.ubuntu.com/t/monday-22nd-october-2018/8414

or the prior week

https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/monday-15th-october-2018/8296/9

Will Cooke (Desktop Team lead), posts it weekly, with members adding their 'reports' progressively...